# Undefined index: varieble obtenida por AJAX

Tags: php, html, ajax

Buenos días comunidad me enfrento a un problema que no se como resolver y agradecería de su colaboracion

resulta y pasa ue tengo 4 select que van cargado uno dependiendo del otro por peticiones ajax al servidor pues van cargado bien todos lo select pero en el momento de enviar las variable que son las opciones elejidas de los select el servidos no identifica esas variables

este es el archivo php que llena el select

```
<?php

session_start();
include_once '../include_conexion.php';

$proceso = strip_tags(utf8_decode($_POST['proceso']));

 $sql = "SELECT c.pqr_con_are_id, a.nombre FROM pqr_control_areas c
        INNER JOIN pqr_areas a
        ON c.pqr_con_are_id = a.id
        WHERE c.pqr_con_tip_id = '$proceso' ";

 $result = $connection->query($sql);

    $cadena="<label for='proceso'>Proceso:</label>
            <select class='form-control' name='proceso' id='lista4' onkeypress='return tabular(event,this)' required>
            <option value=''>Seleccione</option>"; 

    while ($ver = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
        $cadena=$cadena.'<option value='.$ver[0].'>'.utf8_encode($ver[1]).'</option>';
    }

    echo $cadena."</select>";

 mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

y en el html lo muestro asi

```
<div class="col-md-4 mb-4 md-form" id="select2lista"></div>
```

bueno cuando intento pasar variable del select ""name=proceso"" por un form

```
$proceso = $connection->real_escape_string(utf8_decode($_POST['proceso']));
```

sale este error

Notice: Undefined index: proceso

alguien me puede ayudar como puedo obtener esa variable que viene por ajax y se escribe en un div

Comment: agrega el AJAX respectivo por favor

Answer (score 1):

Agrega el ajax.

Sin embargo yo presencie un error asi programando y lo solucioné asi:

```
var Pepe = "Mi Nombre";
    var FormData = {'data': Pepe}

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "url",
        data: FormData,
        dataType: "HTML"
    });
```

Asi logre enviar una variable por ajax.